# Facebook login + nonfacewbook

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I am a little lost on how best to integrate both Facebook login and a login for non face book users ?

Can anyone offer a suggestion. Not looking for code, just best methodology please.

Trying avoid users having to get confused between both, essentially the ideal would be them to be able to login if they already have a facebook account, but how to get them onto the site with an account with they don't use facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have both login & facebook connect buttons, I have a methodology which is used on my web startup.

1. In PHP SDK example, there is a field namely `$loginUrl`. You should have a facebook connect link with `$loginUrl`.
2. Have a field in your database like "fb_conn" which is a tiny int or boolean type. fb_conn = 1 means the user is connected to the system with facebook account.
3. When the user firstly clicks the facebook connect button, you should check whether there are existing registrations based on user_name or email field. If there exist, then perform a facebook login in your database with sql query
4. If there are no previous registrations in that account, have a static key, concat with some of the user's unique field and md5 them. For instance ,

   ```
   $fb_pass =  md5( $_SESSION['fb_email'] ."124cc33" ) ;
   ```
5. Insert into mysql database with facebook user name and password with $fb_pass. After that, in facebook login function, you can check the password is true or not by concating fb_email with static key "124cc33". By this way, facebook logged will be same as normal login function in your database. The only change is the input fields in password.
6. Merge facebook account with normal account (by just updating fb_conn as 1) if the user tries to  connect from facebook who already got an account previously.

Comment: it's a little bit complicated to understand. feel free to ask any questions

Comment: Sounds good Ara, I'll give this a go and if I have issues will return. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks Aacanakin. Seem to be getting something together which is working.

Answer (score 0):

you can have your custom login form and also add the facebook login. if users have fb account, they can login with it else they can create an account with your site and login with your custom form. does that answer your question?